# Postfix to infix optimization

Tags: java, performance, optimization, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to build a syntax from a postfix input. This is my current code, and it's not quite fast enough. t is a BufferedInputStream object, and the readNext() reads the next number in the input.

Any ideas how to optimize the performance of this code, or another way of doing it that is faster?

```
for(int j = t.read();t.available()>0;j=t.read()) {
    if(j==32) continue;
    if(j==43||j==45||j==42||j==47) {

        Node i = stack.pop();
        Node k = stack.pop();
        stack.push(new Node(k,i,j));
    }else {
            int number = readNext(j);
            stack.push(new Node(number));
    }
        }
```

Comment: Not a speed optimization, but using `' '` instead of 32 (etc) would make the meaning of the code much clearer.

Comment: definetly agree, but it actually seem to run a little bit slower.

Comment: There is no difference in the bytecode between the two. If you are observing a difference, you aren't measuring correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not use `.available()`. It's a weird method. It does what its specification says it does, but if you carefully read that specification, you realize that what it does is effectively useless. Specifically, `available()` can return 0 even though the stream hasn't closed yet. (This is trivial to show by reading from standard in and not typing for a while). The right way to detect end-of-input is to check the number that `read()` returns: It'll return `-1` when the stream ends.
- As to your question: Nothing in this code is slow. So, either it's already going as fast as possible, or, the inputstream you're reading from has inherent inefficiencies which I can't tell you about because you haven't shown that part of the code, or, that `readNext()` method is the source of the slowness.

Comment: thank you, changing the available() made the code a lot faster!